# Open or play file with compatible apps from my android app

Tags: java, android

I have listed all the files from sdcard in Listview, so I want to play clicked file with compatible installed application. I tried all the related questions and their correct answers, but I still have a problem when I click on the file and choose compatible app to play. the chosen app only open without playing clicked file
here is my code:

```
    private void onFileClick(String path) {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);

    shareIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    // get file type
    String type;
    String extenstion = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(o.getPath());
    if (extenstion != null) {

        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extenstion);
        shareIntent.setType(type);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, extenstion.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Play with"));
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: @pskink ,@CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void onFileClick(String path) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);

    shareIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    // get file type
    String type;
    String extenstion = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(o.getPath());
    if (extenstion != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extenstion);
        shareIntent.setType(type);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, extenstion.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Play with"));
}
```